# Excel File with Null Value with String Issue

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I get NullPointerException when I run this code -

```
File src = new File("C:\\myxl.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

String mystr=sh1.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
WebElement mwe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='" + mystr + "']"));

if (mystr.contains(null))
{
System.out.println("there is Nothing");
}
else 
{
act.doubleClick(mwe).perform();
```

What do I change in the code so that if the value in that column and row is empty it will print "there is Nothing" instead of giving me a NullPointerException or else it will take some action with the element.

P.S. This is part a of a Selenium webdriver script

Comment: if (mystr == null)

Comment: @AtulKumbhar Still it gives me this error

Comment: stacktrace please?

Comment: @AtulKumbhar a student here not sure what do you mean by stacktrace yet, Sorry. If you mean where do i get the  NullPointerException I get it on line 157 which is this line of code String mystr=sh1.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue();

Comment: you answered the question then...check which one of these is null before setting mystr:

      if(sh1 != null && sh1.getRow(1) != null && sh1.getRow(1).getCell(4) != null)
     mystr=sh1.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue();

Comment: @AtulKumbhar Thank you so much it worked.

Comment: Final code looks like this, if anyone needs it, thanks so much @Atul again`File src = new File("C:\\myxl.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

if (sh1 != null && sh1.getRow(1) != null && sh1.getRow(1).getCell(4) != null) { 

mystr=sh1.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
WebElement mwe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title='" + mystr + "']"));
act.doubleClick(mwe).perform();

else 
{
System.out.println("there is Nothing");
}
`